# Assign SharePoint document permissions to a custom group

Tags: sharepoint

How do I add a custom group to this image library? I created a group at the site level which contains a list of users from AD but there is no option for me to add this group to this specific folder.
I have also created a group at the AD level but the SharePoint functionality only allows for individual users to be added to one of the groups already listed.

I stopped inheriting permissions from the top level site in order to manage access to certain folders but I don't seem to have that option.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following the steps:

1. From permissions page (shown in your question), click on "Grant Permissions"
2. Search name of group in first text box and select group from suggestions
3. Click on "SHOW OPTIONS"
4. Select Permission level as per your requirements
5. Click "Share"

[image]

**Documentation**: [Customize permissions for a SharePoint list or library](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-permissions-for-a-sharepoint-list-or-library-02d770f3-59eb-4910-a608-5f84cc297782)